# Composer update fails on own package

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I've made a Composer package called `nickdekruijk/larapages`. It works fine when I do a `composer required nickdekruijk/larapages` for the first time. But after I add the service provider to `config/app.php` I can't run `composer update` anymore:

> ```
> $ composer update
> > php artisan clear-compiled
> Loading composer repositories with package information
> Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
> Nothing to install or update
> Generating autoload files
> > php artisan optimize
>
>   [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
>   Class 'NickDeKruijk\LaraPages\LaraPagesServiceProvider' not found
> ```

The only workaround so far is to remove the service provider (or comment the line) from `config/app.php`, run `composer update`, then put it back (uncomment) again which is pretty annoying. Am I doing something wrong? Do I need to fix my package maybe?

Comment: Do you have any scripts set in your composer.json (pre/post-install-cmd, pre/post-update-cmd)?

Comment: Well, I just checked your package on GitHut and you are using the post-update-cmd script to publish vendor files. Run the same composer update composer with the no-scripts option, like this: composer update --no-scripts.

Comment: @subzeta I removed the post-update-cmd from my composer.json in the package. Unfortunately that doesn't help. (Even removed the package from the laravel app and required it again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I fixed it!
Problem was the autoloader.
First when I moved the files from src/* to src/NickDeKruijk/LaraPages/* composer update was working just fine. But I didn't want to move the files permanently (screwing up my git repo) so I added this to the package composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "NickDeKruijk\\LaraPages\\": "src/"
    }
}
```

Now I can run composer update just fine!

Answer (score 0):

If the package is already installed, there shouldn't be an issue. Are you sure there isn't a problem with the namespacing of the package, and that the class actually exists?

As a workaround, one which is helpful for any related issue where a service provider isn't actually available yet, you can run Composer and not have it run Laravel's scripts (which cause the error).

```
composer update --no-scripts
```